# GET CourseWork by Date Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

I'm curious as to how to obtain assignments for a specific date from a user's classroom. I know you can use calendar, although it doesn't provide the coursework meta or individually assigned items.

Thanks, Will

Comment: There's no 'q' search parameter for courseWork but you can get started by using [courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) which should return all the courseWork for you and use 'orderBy' to sort the ordering. After that, check the dates and write your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that method gets ALL coursework regardless of its submission status. There is also a limit on how many items it retrieves. It pulls too many items and is slow.